# How do I delete a table in powerpoint using VBa?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

So I'm trying to get a table deleted from a powerpoint that is opened using VBa, and I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried a few things but they never have any effect or usually just give me an error.

So far I have gotten the following, which opens a specific powerpoint and copies in a specific table to the first slide. I really would like to be able to delete the table that is already there and replace it with the new one.

How would I go about doing this? Code below:

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Range Into a New PowerPoint Presentation

Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myShapeRange As PowerPoint.Shape

'Copy Range from Excel
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[#ALL]")

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

'Create a New Presentation
Set myPresentation =         PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("Y:\Projects\VBa\vbatest2.pptx")

'Add a slide to the Presentation
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Item(1)

'Delete current table in presentation
'ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Delete

'Copy Excel Range
rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
 mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteSourceFormatting
 Set myShapeRange = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position:
  myShapeRange.Left = 20
  myShapeRange.Top = 100
  myShapeRange.Height = 400
  myShapeRange.Width = 900

'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Delete
```

Place code above just after

```
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Item(1)
```

When I used this it deleted my table from my powerpoint however it was only a table in the slide, you may need to change the number in shapes to get this to work for you. I also don't know how it will fair will continued use, you may need to keep changing the number.

I used [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746738.aspx/%22This22%)
to find out how to delete items from powerpoint

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(5).Table.Rows(3).Delete
```

Is the origonal code from the site linked and was adapted using trial and error

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744177.aspx)
Explains shapes a bit more, hope it helps. In a basic overview it basicly says that in powerpoint most items you can enter in it are called shapes

If you want me to explain anything further just leave a comment and I shall try to do so

Comment: This worked, just made sure to set 

    Shapes(NUMBER)

To the correct value for the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling this function to delete all tables from the specified slide:

```
Option Explicit

' Deletes all tables from the specified slide (table shapes and tables within placeholders)
' Returns the number of tables deleted
' Written by Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd. (http://youpresent.co.uk)
Public Function DeleteTablesFromSlide(mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide) As Long
  Dim lCntr As Long
  Dim lTables As Long
  ' Count backwards when deleting items from a collection
  For lCntr = mySlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    With mySlide.Shapes(lCntr)
      Select Case .Type
        Case msoTable: .Delete: lTables = lTables + 1 ' msoTable = 19
        Case msoPlaceholder ' msoPlaceholder = 19
          If .PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoTable Then .Delete: lTables = lTables + 1
      End Select
    End With
  Next
  DeleteTablesFromSlide = lTables
End Function
```

Call with:

```
DeleteTablesFromSlide mySlide
```